# Product title above the product price in shopify

Tags: shopify

I want product title to be on the top of the price.

[image: reordering the price]

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very specific to the theme you are using. You need to find which file is being used for product item. Generally its under "snippets" folder and named as "product-grid-item.liquid"  ( it can be different in your theme )

Next you need to move your product title code in that file which looks like this

`{{ product_title }}`

Then you need to move that above the price tag code which may look like this

`{{ featured.price | money }}`  or  `{{ product.price | money }}`

You will need experience with html coding to make the changes properly.

Or you can download and share the theme files with me so that i can tell you exactly what changes you need done.